# NullReferenceException in ValidateInputDevices

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application and I get multiple error reports for the same error, this error never happened on my machine - only on customer's machines.

Most error reports are anonymous - so I have almost no additional information.

The error and full stack trace are:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ValidateInputDevices(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.FireTick(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Anyone has any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Impossible without any more info

Comment: It appears that ValidateInputDevices is not thread-safe when accessing it's _hitTestInvalidatedAsyncOperation field. Are you using threads in your application?

Comment: @CodeNaked - I create a worker thread once in a while, but I'm not doing anything fancy and the worker thread never interacts directly with the GUI (only using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke), most of the time the app is single threaded.

Comment: yes, perhaps you should include whatever additional information you do have.

Answer (score 0):

After disassembling the method with .NET Reflector, I think this is a race condition in WPF in .NET 3.5. Here's the disassembly of the method:

```
private void ValidateInputDevices(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this._hitTestInvalidatedAsyncOperation.Priority = DispatcherPriority.Input;
    this._inputTimer.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

`InputManager.HitTestInvalidatedAsyncCallback` sets `this._hitTestInvalidatedAsyncOperation = null`; if the DispatcherTimer (that calls `ValidateInputDevices`) fires after this line of code executes, it will crash with a `NullReferenceException` trying to set the Priority.

This bug appears to have been fixed in .NET 4; disassembling the same method in WPF 4 gives this code:

```
private void ValidateInputDevices(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this._hitTestInvalidatedAsyncOperation != null)
    {
        this._hitTestInvalidatedAsyncOperation.Priority = DispatcherPriority.Input;
    }
    this._inputTimer.IsEnabled = false;
}
```